# АпОстроф и АпострОф

Tags: орфоэпия, фонетика

Известно, что ударение в словах — процесс естественный (т. е. лингвисты фиксируют лишь то, что стало объективной реальностью; тот или иной вариант стал достаточно распространенным). Известно также, что в русском языке в многосложных словах ударение обычно тяготеет к центру. Так как же так получилось, что в слове "апостроф" ударение сместилось на последний слог? Уже в ушаковском словаре ударение на втором слоге считается устаревшим. Есть ли какие-нибудь сведения об этом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

АпострОф - французский вариант, из фр. языка слово было заимствовано, апОстроф - греческий первоисточник.

Резниченко предлагает выучить правильную форму так: апострОф - запятАя.

Comment: Да, это я знаю. Но меня интересует, почему сместилось ударение. Ведь намного легче произносить "апОстроф''.

Comment: Думаю, что это, скорее, волевое решение. Слово малоупотребительное, вряд ли на него мог бы  оказать влияние эмпирический закон о смещении ударения к центру.

Comment: Да, мне тоже так кажется.

Comment: *это, скорее, волевое решение* — точнее говоря, волюнтаристское.